# W3C Markup Validation Service with Selenium

Tags: selenium, tdd

I have read something about TDD. My field is web development. 
Namely server side (Python + Django).
In a book I read: let's check whether our local web page has a 'html' tag.

I would say that for learning purposes it is ok. But a real web page should be validated by https://validator.w3.org/

They say that even for famous web sites not every page passes the validation. Well, let us assume that we decided to develop a nice web site and our policy is 100 % passing of the validation.

Well, the plan seems to look like we should automatically submit our web page to the validator and check for errors. How can it be done?

By the way, I don't have a public IP.

Is it a good plan to:
1) Pay more to ones Internet provider and get a public IP.
2) Run a webserver in debug mode. In this case at the development stage the web site will be visible from a real world. 
3) Pass the address of the web page being developed to the validator via Selenium?
4) Check for errors via Selenium again.

Is it a good idea or is there a better plan? Can I get by without a public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can download a copy of the W3C validation program and run it locally](https://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html).

There are also a number of other offline HTML validators such as [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) and [Total Validator](https://www.totalvalidator.com/).

You might also consider running the validation as a part of [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). There are plugins for Jenkins and other CI servers such as the [Unicorn Validation plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unicorn+Validation+Plugin).